# XML: How can i select the first element based on a condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I Have an XML and i was given a condition that filters the first position of every wd:Job_Profile that haves the wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID with a value of 'BB'

I did not manage to output the file like i needed

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="ASD">
<wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Job_Profile_group>
            <wd:Job_Profile>FM9</wd:Job_Profile>
        </wd:Job_Profile_group>
        <wd:Job_Classifications_group>
            <wd:JOBClassification wd:Descriptor="01BB - BUSINESS EXECUTION (01 BUILDING BLOCK)">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">459d562212ea01a695f50ff4ac009601</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">JOB_CLASS_GLOBAL_BEX#BBO</wd:ID>
            </wd:JOBClassification>
            <wd:JOBClassification_ID>01BB</wd:JOBClassification_ID>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID>BB</wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Group wd:Descriptor="01 BUILDING BLOCK">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">459d562212ea01cfdf590ff4ac009301</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">JOB_CLASS_Building_Block#BB</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Classification_Group>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Description>BUSINESS EXECUTION</wd:Job_Classification_Description>
            <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
        </wd:Job_Classifications_group>
        <wd:Job_Classifications_group>
            <wd:JOBClassification wd:Descriptor="01BB - FRONT (01 BUILDING BLOCK)">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">459d562212ea01e0e39f0ff4ac009401</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Reference_ID">JOB_CLASS_GLOBAL_FRONT#BBF</wd:ID>
            </wd:JOBClassification>
            <wd:JOBClassification_ID>01BB</wd:JOBClassification_ID>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID>BB</wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Group wd:Descriptor="01 BUILDING BLOCK">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">459d562212ea01cfdf590ff4ac009301</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Job_Classification_Group_ID">JOB_CLASS_Building_Block#BB</wd:ID>
            </wd:Job_Classification_Group>
            <wd:Job_Classification_Description>FRONT</wd:Job_Classification_Description>
            <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
        </wd:Job_Classifications_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    </wd:Report_Data>
```

My transformation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:wd="ASD" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
 xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
    <!--Variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xd;&#xa;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="quote" select="'&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
    <xsl:variable name="EMPTY" select="''"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doublequotes" select="'&quot;&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;"> 
            <Header xtt:separator="," xtt:truncate="true" xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><column1>g_job_profile_id</column1><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><Column2>gf_job_classification_id</Column2><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><Column3>gf_job_classification_name</Column3><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><Column4>gf_job_classification_gp_id</Column4><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$quote"/><Column5>g_active_ind_type</Column5><xsl:value-of select="$quote"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            </Header>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="wd:Report_Data"/>
        </File>
    </xsl:template>

    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">
     <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(wd:JOBClassification_ID) &lt;=80 and not(wd:Report_Entry/wd:Job_Profile_Group/wd:Job_Profile = '')">
        <Record xtt:truncate="true" xtt:quotes="always" xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
            <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Job_Classifications_group">
                <xsl:variable name="jobGroupID" select="wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID"/>
                 <xsl:variable name="jobProfileID" select="../wd:Job_Profile_group[1]/wd:Job_Profile"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length(../wd:Job_Profile_group/wd:Job_Profile)&lt;=3 ">
        
                <!-- Variable declarations have been omitted. -->
                <!-- <Employee xtt:target="{$EmployeeName}"
            xtt:targetWID="{$EmployeeWID}"
            xtt:quotes="csv"
            xtt:endTag="&#xD;&#xA;"> -->
                <Job_Classifications xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="always" xtt:truncate="true">
                
                <!--Job Profile-->
                
                    <Job_Profile xtt:required="true" xtt:truncate="true"  xtt:maxLength="3" xtt:reportTruncation="warning">
                    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(../wd:Job_Profile_group/wd:Job_Profile) > 3 ">
            <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
            </xsl:when>
            
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(../wd:Job_Profile_group/wd:Job_Profile,$EMPTY)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Job_Profile>
                    
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <!-- Job Classification ID-->
                
                <Job_Classification_ID xtt:required="true" xtt:maxLength="80" xtt:truncate="true" xtt:reportTruncation="warning" xtt:severity="error">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:JOBClassification/wd:ID [@wd:type='Job_Classification_Reference_ID'],$EMPTY)"/> 
                    </Job_Classification_ID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                    <!-- Job Classification Description-->
                    <Job_Classification_Description xtt:required="true" xtt:truncate="true"  xtt:maxLength="254" xtt:reportTruncation="warning" xtt:severity="warning">
                        <xsl:value-of select="replace(concat(wd:Job_Classification_Description,$EMPTY), '^(&quot;?)(.+)\1(.*)$', '$2$3')"/> 
                    </Job_Classification_Description>
                    
                        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                    
                
                        <!-- Job Classification Group ID--> 
                        
                        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID) > 5">
            <Job_Classification_Group xtt:required="false" xtt:truncate="true"  xtt:maxLength="5" xtt:reportTruncation="warning" xtt:severity="warning">
            <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
            </Job_Classification_Group>
            <errormessage xtt:omit="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:target="Job Classification Group" xtt:targetWID="{wd:Job_Classification_Group/wd:ID [@wd:type='WID']}" xtt:message="El registro supera los 5 caracteres - ID Grupo de Clasificacion de Puesto "> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                </errormessage>
            </xsl:when>
          
            <xsl:otherwise>
             <Job_Classification_Group>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Job_Classification_Group_ID,$EMPTY)"/> 
</Job_Classification_Group>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            
                        </xsl:choose>
                    
                            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                            <!-- Inactive-->
                    
                
                    <Inactive xtt:maxLength="1" xtt:required="true">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="wd:Inactive = '1'">
                                <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="wd:Inactive = '0'">
                            <xsl:text>Y</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </Inactive>
                    
                </Job_Classifications>
                <!--  </Employee> -->
<xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Record>
        </xsl:when>
    
        <xsl:otherwise>
        <errormessage xtt:omit="true" xtt:severity="error" xtt:message="El registro no cumple las condiciones del formato requerido o está vacío - Perfil de Puesto - ID de Clasificacion de Perfil de Puesto - Nombre de Clasificacion de Puesto - ID Grupo de Clasificacion de Puesto ">  
                <xsl:value-of select="$EMPTY"/>
                </errormessage>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i apply the transformation, it returns me two rows with the BB value, but i need just one..

The output text that i need is something like this:

```
"g_job_profile_id","gf_job_classification_id","gf_job_classification_name","gf_job_classification_gp_id","g_active_ind_type"
FM9,JOB_CLASS_GLOBAL_BEX#BBO,BUSINESS EXECUTION,BB,Y
```

This was tested on XSLT Fiddle, i share my link so you can see it:
http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rY7/1

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: i fixed that one, in the last  part of the description is a link to check what the transformation does